# Is it legal for an L1 US visa holder to trade in "Options" in USA?

Tags: usa, legal

I am L1 visa holder working in USA for the last 2 years and I want to trade in Options. Is it legal to do so?

Comment: Would you be trading options for yourself? Or would you be working at the behest of someone else? Always ask an immigration attorney, but if you're not getting paid (i.e. receive a 1099 or W-2 form, or asked for your SSN for any "employment" paperwork) then you'll probably be okay.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic it asks for legal advice.